# Como ejecutar el metodo POST de un formulario que consume APIS externas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express

Antes que nada aclaro estoy trabajando con JavaScript, Express, Node JS. Tengo problemas para  ejecutar el metodo POST de un formulario de registro de usuarios que consume las APIS del gobierno con el listado de provincias y una vez seleccionada la misma el de localidades.

El formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form action='/user/register/' method='POST' class='register-form'>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Nombre y Apellido (*)</p>
                    <input type='text' name='nombre'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Cómo te gustaría que te llamemos?</p>
                    <input type='text' name='apodo'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Foto de Perfil</p>
                    <input type='file' name='avatar' class='foto-input'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Email(*)</p>
                    <input type='email' name='email'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Teléfono</p>
                    <input type='number' name='telefono'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Provincia</p>
                    <select name='provincia'>
                        <option selected>Seleccioná tu provincia
                        <% for( let i=0; i < listado.length; i++ ) { %>
                            <option>
                                <%= listado[i].nombre %>
                            </option>
                            <% } %>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Localidad</p>
                    <select name='localidad'>
                        <option selected>Seleccioná tu Localidad
                            <% for( let i=0; i < listado.length; i++ ) { %>
                                <option>
                                    <%= ciudades[i].nombre %>
                                </option>
                                <% } %>
                            </option>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Dirección (*)</p>
                    <input type='text' name='direccion'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Contraseña (*)</p>
                    <input type='password' name='contraseña'>
                </div>
                <div class='complete-container'>
                    <p>Confirmar Contraseña (*)</p>
                    <input type='password' name='contraseñacheck'>
                </div>
                <div class='button-box'>
                    <button type='submit' class='create-button'>CONFIRMA TU CUENTA</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Y el controlador es el mismo:

```
register: (req,res) => {
        fetch('https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/provincias')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.render('register', {listado: data.provincias})
        })

        let pciaElegida = req.body.provincia;

        fetch('https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/localidades?provincia='+pciaElegida+'&max=1000&campos=nombre')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.render('register', {ciudades: data.localidades})
        })
    }
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me arroja el error de que pronvincia es undefined, entiendo que el req.body no esta cumpliendo su funcion y no trae el request. Como puedo traer este dato?

Comment: Para obtener el nombre podrías hacer `const {provincia: nombre} = req.body` pero no veo donde obtienes el valor de la opción seleccionada del select. Igual los dos fetch se ejecutan al mismo tiempo, entonces podrías usar async await para el segundo fetch.

Comment: Creo que tienes un error al armar el `select` de provincias en tu `HTML`, estás encerrando cada `option` de provincia en el `option` "Seleccioná tu provincia". Quizás el error lo tengas en que la función `register` quizás venga de una petición asíncrona y se llame sin haber terminado de ejecutarse la petición. ¿Puedes poner el código desde donde se llama a la función `register`?

Comment: Nunca había visto que se llamara dos veces a `res.render` y en principio pensaría que eso es inválido... por lo que veo, lo que quieres es consultar la lista de provincias y la lista de localidades de esa provincia y retornar ambos datos en la respuesta? Si es así, deberías entonces esperar que ambas peticiones respondan antes de enviar una respuesta en `res.render`

Comment: No solo hay problemas en el uso de `res.render`, sino que además no estás trabajando correctamente con la asincronía inherente a las peticiones con `fetch`.

Comment: Pude solucionarlo con eventos desde js usando el DOM, Muchas gracias!